# Recursive replace with Java regular expression?

Tags: java, regex, recursion

I can replace `ABC(10,5)` with `(10)%(5)` using:

```
replaceAll("ABC\\(([^,]*)\\,([^,]*)\\)", "($1)%($2)")
```

but I'm unable to figure out how to do it for `ABC(ABC(20,2),5)` or `ABC(ABC(30,2),3+2)`.

If I'm able to convert to `((20)%(2))%5` how can I convert back to `ABC(ABC(20,2),5)`?

Thanks,
j

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44570869/363573

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to answer about the first question. I was not able to do the task in a single `replaceAll`. I don't think it is even achievable. However if I use loop then this should do the work for you:

```
    String termString = "([0-9+\\-*/()%]*)";
    String pattern = "ABC\\(" + termString + "\\," + termString + "\\)";
    String [] strings = {"ABC(10,5)", "ABC(ABC(20,2),5)", "ABC(ABC(30,2),3+2)"};
    for (String str : strings) {
        while (true) {
            String replaced = str.replaceAll(pattern, "($1)%($2)");
            if (replaced.equals(str)) {
                break;
            }
            str = replaced;
        }
        System.out.println(str);
    }
```

I am assuming you are writing parser for numeric expressions, thus the definition of term `termString = "([0-9+\\-*/()%]*)"`. It outputs this:

```
(10)%(5)
((20)%(2))%(5)
((30)%(2))%(3+2)
```

**EDIT** As per the OP request I add the code for decoding the strings. It is a bit more hacky than the forward scenario:

```
    String [] encoded = {"(10)%(5)", "((20)%(2))%(5)", "((30)%(2))%(3+2)"};
    String decodeTerm = "([0-9+\\-*ABC\\[\\],]*)";
    String decodePattern = "\\(" + decodeTerm + "\\)%\\(" + decodeTerm + "\\)";
    for (String str : encoded) {
        while (true) {
            String replaced = str.replaceAll(decodePattern, "ABC[$1,$2]");
            if (replaced.equals(str)) {
                break;
            }
            str = replaced;
        }
        str = str.replaceAll("\\[", "(");
        str = str.replaceAll("\\]", ")");
        System.out.println(str);
    }
```

And the output is:

```
ABC(10,5)
ABC(ABC(20,2),5)
ABC(ABC(30,2),3+2)
```

Comment: Thank you Boris. I having difficulties to convert it back to ABC(10,5) recursively as well. Kindly advise.

Comment: Ok I have added my solution to this question too.

Comment: Thanks Boris. The decoder looks great. I just need to change it a bit to able to decode such ((60+3))%((5-3)) to ABC((60+3),(5-3)).

Comment: I also working to decode complex enough like this ((10+1))%((6-2)) + ((9-5/(2+1)))%(1).

Comment: Boris. I unable to decode ((10+1))%((6-2)) + ((9-5/(2+1)))%(1). I decided to create another separate question for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9757488/java-regex-how-to-replace-all-character-inside-a-bracket/9757920#9757920. Appreciate if you have any suggestion.

Comment: I think I can solve your problem, however not using regex. However I feel demotivated by the lack of appreciation on your side.

Comment: Oh no Boris. Sorry. I think there is a misunderstanding here. I created that question is because decoding might be more complicated so needed more opinion on it and is nothing to do with your solution. Your solution is great I honestly happy when you give me some idea when I needed it the most. I applied your solution and it works great only when I realise that regex might not able to solve the decoding part somehow. Thanks Boris.

Answer (score 1):

You can start evaluating the inner most reducable expressions first, till no more redux exists. However you have to take care of other `,`, `(` and `)`. The solution of @BorisStrandjev is better, more bullet proof.

```
String infix(String expr) {
    // Use place holders for '(' and ')' to use regex [^,()].
    expr = expr.replaceAll("(?!ABC)\\(", "<<");
    expr = expr.replaceAll("(?!ABC)\\)", ">>");
    for (;;) {
        String expr2 = expr.replaceAll("ABC\\(([^,()]*)\\,([^,()]*)\\)",
                "<<$1>>%<<$2>>");
        if (expr2 == expr)
            break;
        expr = expr2;
    }
    expr = expr.replaceAll("<<", ")");
    expr = expr.replaceAll(">>", ")");
    return expr;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use this Regular Expressions library https://github.com/florianingerl/com.florianingerl.util.regex , that also supports Recursive Regular Expressions.

Converting ABC(ABC(20,2),5) to ((20)%(2))%(5) looks like this:

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<abc>ABC\\((?<arg1>(?:(?'abc')|[^,])+)\\,(?<arg2>(?:(?'abc')|[^)])+)\\))");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("ABC(ABC(20,2),5)");
    String replacement = matcher.replaceAll(new DefaultCaptureReplacer() {
        @Override
        public String replace(CaptureTreeNode node) {
            if ("abc".equals(node.getGroupName())) {
                return "(" + replace(node.getChildren().get(0)) + ")%(" + replace(node.getChildren().get(1)) + ")";
            } else
                return super.replace(node);
        }

    });
    System.out.println(replacement);
    assertEquals("((20)%(2))%(5)", replacement);
```

Converting back again, i.e. from ((20)%(2))%(5) to ABC(ABC(20,2),5) looks like this:

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<fraction>(?<arg>\\(((?:(?'fraction')|[^)])+)\\))%(?'arg'))");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("((20)%(2))%(5)");
    String replacement = matcher.replaceAll(new DefaultCaptureReplacer() {
        @Override
        public String replace(CaptureTreeNode node) {
            if ("fraction".equals(node.getGroupName())) {
                return "ABC(" + replace(node.getChildren().get(0)) + "," + replace(node.getChildren().get(1)) + ")";
            } else if ("arg".equals(node.getGroupName())) {
                return replace(node.getChildren().get(0));
            } else
                return super.replace(node);
        }

    });
    System.out.println(replacement);
    assertEquals("ABC(ABC(20,2),5)", replacement);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to rewrite the string using the Polish notation and then replace any **% X Y** with **ABC(X,Y)**.

[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_notation)'s the wiki link for the Polish notation.

The problem is that you need to find out which rewrite of **ABC(X,Y)** occurred first when you recursively replaced them in your string. The Polish notation is useful for "deciphering" the order that these rewrites occur and is widely used in expression evaluation.

You can do this by using a stack and recording which replace occurred first: find the inner-most set of parentheses, push only that expression onto the stack, then remove that from your string. When you want to reconstruct the expression original expression, just start at the top of the stack and apply the reverse transformation **(X)%(Y)** -> **ABC(X,Y)**.

This is somewhat a form of the Polish notation, with the only difference being that you don't store the entire expression as a string, but rather store it in a stack for easier processing.

In short, when replacing, start with the inner-most terms (the ones that have no parentheses in them) and apply the reverse replace.

It may be helpful to use **(X)%(Y)** -> **ABC{X,Y}** as an intermediary rewrite rule, then rewrite the curly brackets as round brackets. This way it will be easier to determine which is the inner-most term, as the new terms won't use round brackets. Also it is easier to implement, but not as elegant.