# Java regex: How to replace all character inside a bracket?

Tags: java, regex, nested, recursive-regex

How do I able to replace:

```
((90+1)%(100-4)) + ((90+1)%(100-4/(6-4))) - (var1%(var2%var3(var4-var5)))
```

with

```
XYZ((90+1),(100-4)) + XYZ((90+1),100-4/(6-4)) - XYZ(var1,XYZ(var2,var3(var4-var5)))
```

with regex?

Thanks,
J

Comment: See [similar question][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9734069/recursive-replace-with-java-regular-expression/9734720#9734720

Answer (score 1):

this doesn't really look like a very good job for a regex. It looks like you might want to write a quick recursive descent parser instead. If I understand you correctly, you want to replace the infix operator % with a function name XYZ?

So (expression % expression) becomes XYZ(expression, expression)

This looks like a good resource to study: http://www.cs.uky.edu/~lewis/essays/compilers/rec-des.html

Comment: Yes. I thought this is a very common problem. I am almost giving up using regex on this expecially handling nested and recursive replacement. I heard about the tree structure able to do the trick. The link that you gave might help. It might take me more time to interpret it into Java code. Any help on this really appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about regex, but try looking at this, especially 9 and 10:
http://www.mkyong.com/regular-expressions/10-java-regular-expression-examples-you-should-know/

And of course:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

You could at least check them out until an in depth answer comes along.

Answer (score 0):

See this code:

```
    String input = "((90+1)%(100-4)) + ((90+1)%(100-4/(6-4))) - (var1%(var2%var3(var4-var5)))";
    input = input.replaceAll("%", ",");
    int level = 0;
    List<Integer> targetStack = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    List<Integer> splitIndices = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    // add the index of last character as default checkpoint
    splitIndices.add(input.length());
    for (int i = input.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (input.charAt(i) == ',') {
            targetStack.add(level - 1);
        } else if (input.charAt(i) == ')') {
            level++;
        }
        else if (input.charAt(i) == '(') {
            level--;
            if (!targetStack.isEmpty() && level == targetStack.get(targetStack.size() - 1)) {
                splitIndices.add(i);
            }
        }
    }
    Collections.reverse(splitIndices); // reversing the indices so that they are in increasing order
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 1; i < splitIndices.size(); i++) {
        result.append("XYZ");
        result.append(input.substring(splitIndices.get(i - 1), splitIndices.get(i)));
    }
    System.out.println(result);
```

The output is as you expect it:

```
XYZ((90+1),(100-4)) + XYZ((90+1),(100-4/(6-4))) - XYZ(var1,XYZ(var2,var3(var4-var5)))
```

However keep in mind that it is a bit hacky and it might not work exactly as you expect it. Btw, I had to change a bit the output I added couple of brackets: XYZ((90+1), **(** 100-4/(6-4 **)** )) because otherwise you were not following your own conventions. Hopefully this code helps you. For me it was a good exercise at least.

Comment: Thank you Boris. I tried a few unit test some failing. Like (99)%(100) i probably need to add ((99)%(100)) when i encode that time and for XYZ(3+4,XYZ(XYZ(XYZ(XYZ(99,100),88),6),5+2)) encoded into (3+4)%(((((99)%(100))%(88))%(6))%(5+2)) might probably need to change as well in order to decode using algorithm above back to XYZ(3+4,XYZ(XYZ(XYZ(XYZ(99,100),88),6),5+2)). I might need to adjust the encoding function else it will decoded differently. I trying adding more brackets but still failing.

Comment: Yes sorry. I have bugs in my code. I am going to fix it and then repost the correct solution

Answer (score 0):

Would it satisfy your requirements to do the following:

1. Find `(` at first position or preceded by space and replace it with `XYZ(`
2. Find `%` and replace it with `,`

If those two instructions are sufficient and satisfactory, then you could transform the original string in three "moves":

1. Replace `^\(` with `XYZ(`
2. Replace `\(` with `XYZ(`
3. Replace `%` with `,`